# SQLITE::Statement::execute() vs SQLITE::Database::exec()

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to make a thread safe SQL database with multiple connections and ran into a weird issue. Currently using SQLITECPP Wrapper for this project 
*https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp*

The problem: Following are two code blocks which essentially achieve the same thing. CODE #1 works but CODE #2 throws a SQLITE Disk I/O error. Does anyone know why this happens?

CODE #1

```
        //db is SQLite::Database object
        SQLite::Statement change_to_wal(db,"PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;");
        change_to_wal.executeStep();
        SQLite::Statement query_drop_table(db,"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Corrections");
        query_drop_table.executeStep();
        std::string sql = "CREATE TABLE Corrections(" 
                         "CURRENT_DATE          TEXT    NOT NULL," 
                         "CURRENT_THRESHOLD     INT     NOT NULL);";
        SQLite::Statement add_columns(db,sql);
        add_columns.executeStep();
```

CODE #2:

```
        //db is SQLite::Database object
        db.exec("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;");
        db.exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Corrections");
        std::string sql = "CREATE TABLE Corrections(" 
                         "CURRENT_DATE          TEXT    NOT NULL," 
                         "CURRENT_THRESHOLD     INT     NOT NULL);";
        db.exec(sql);
```